# Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type' in C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I encountered error `CS0029` in LINQ code. The code is not mine, but I have to deal with this code. The complete error message is
`Error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#1> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<AnonymousType#2>`

in code fragment

```
 grouped =
  from r in result
  group r by new
  {
   r.KindOfCalculationsNumber,
   r.KindOfCalculationsCode,
   r.PeriodFor,
   r.SnuType,
   r.SnuName,
   r.IsAssist,
   r.DDS,
   r.DDP,
   r.PRC,
   r.KFTType,
   r.WRK,
   r.NUMERATOR,
   r.DENOMINATOR,
   r.FOVTYPE,
   r.RATEVALUE,
   r.INDFCT,
   r.KFTKV,
   r.OsnNote,
   r.TransferDate,
   r.ExcludeFromItog,
   r.ExcludeFromItogInter,
   r.SnuTypeCode,
   r.TransferType
  }
   into g
   let k = g.Key
   orderby k.SnuTypeCode, k.KindOfCalculationsNumber, k.PeriodFor, g.Min(t => t.SnuNumber)
   select new
   {
    k.KindOfCalculationsNumber,
    k.KindOfCalculationsCode,
    k.PeriodFor,
    k.SnuType,
    k.SnuTypeCode,
    SnuNumber = g.Min(t => t.SnuNumber),
    k.SnuName,
    k.IsAssist,
    k.DDS,
    k.DDP,
    k.PRC,
    k.KFTType,
    k.WRK,
    k.NUMERATOR,
    k.DENOMINATOR,
    k.FOVTYPE,
    k.RATEVALUE,
    k.INDFCT,
    k.KFTKV,
    k.OsnNote,
    TaxDeduction = g.Sum(t => t.TaxDeduction),
    TransferSum = g.Sum(t => t.TransferSum),
    k.TransferDate,
    k.ExcludeFromItog,
    k.ExcludeFromItogInter,
    Sum = g.Sum(t => t.Sum)
   };
```

The error points at line `select new`. Can anyone advise me what is wrong in this code? Something for me to begin with. Full CS file that is being compiled can be downloaded from [https://disk.yandex.ru/d/S3AGUWMciF_HFQ](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: How did you declare `grouped`? Did you re-use it from a different query with different (anonymous) result type? What if you do `var grouped2 = ...` instead?

Comment: Thank you. You comment is indeed an answer to my question. I cannot mark it as answer because you did not post it as an answer. Could you please post you answer as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using different data sets (in your case anonymous types) and trying to assign them to the same variable `grouped`.

You will therefore need to either change how you retrieve the data such that it is the same type, or you can simply declare a new variable to store the data.

Currently your simplified use case is as below:

```
var grouped = new { someValue = 1 };
grouped = new { someValue = 1, anotherValue = 2 }; // fails: Cannot implicitly convert type 'AnonymousType#1' to 'AnonymousType#2'
```

You can resolve that as follows:

```
var grouped = new { someValue = 1 };
var grouped2 = new { someValue = 1, anotherValue = 2 }; // new variable for new data type
grouped = new { someValue = 5 }; // Note that this works because it is the same type as the original value of grouped
```